# Enable shutter sound on take picture

Tags: android, android-camera

How can I enable the shutter sound when the picture is taken?  I have tried this but it is not working ! I am testing it on Galaxy y(target 2.3.6)
Any hints or ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, mPicture);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
private final ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mgr.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    }
};
```

Comment: The `mgr.playSoundEffect` can only use a certain set of flags. More information here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#playSoundEffect(int,%20float)

Answer (score 7):

You should set not null callback

```
        camera.takePicture(
                new Camera.ShutterCallback() { @Override public void onShutter() { } },
                new Camera.PictureCallback() { @Override public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) { } },
                jpegCallback);
```